# Old legacy application doesn't work with TLS 1.2

Tags: tls1.2, legacy

We have an old application that was built years ago by people no one know. Now we are running a project to disable TLS 1.0 & 1.1 globally in our environment and of course this application stops working. The problem is that the application is using old OLEDB driver to connect to it's database hosted on a MSSQL server 2017.
The application itself connects to it's database to create financial reports and is crucial in book endings for that region.
It consist of 2 files, one application file which is basically only executionable and one config file.
This is what the config file consist of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Configuration>
  <Section name="Parameters">
    <Item key="CompanyID" value="XX" />
    <Item key="Company_Name" value="Company Name" />
    <Item key="ServerIp" value="SQLSERVER" />
    <Item key="DbName" value="DATABASE" />
    <Item key="UserID" value="SQLLOGIN" />
    <Item key="UserPass" value="Password" />
  </Section>
</Configuration>
```

I've tried to check within the application settings if it's possible to change driver but there's no such option. There's nothing in the registry that tells the application what driver to use. It's not using an existing ODBC connection.
I was thinking that it might be possible to add a line in the config file telling the application what driver to use when connecting to the database but don't have the knowledge for it nor have I found it while searching around online.

Comment: Do you at least know what technology the app was built with? Is the configuration file named `<MyApp>.exe.config`? This format *resembles* what a .NET application would use, but is crucially not exactly the same as an app.config (notably, capitalization is off). If it *is* a .NET app, not all is necessarily lost, as .NET code is easy to decompile if no obfuscator was used (compiling it back again may be a little more challenging). There is, however, no magic setting that will somehow change the driver if it was hard-coded; this is why connection strings should be used.

Comment: No unfortunately not. The full name of the config file is 'ApplicationConfig.config' and the application file is 'Finance Reporting System.exe'. I did try to change in the registry for .net to use TLS 1.2 as default but still didn't work so my guess is that it's not .net but as you said, could be hardcoded in the application.